# List directories not containing a file which has a variable prefix

Tags: bash, find

I'm checking the output from a script. In some cases the script has failed, and a certain file hasn't been produced.
I want to check whether this file is present in a directory and if not, print the directory name.
The directories look like:

```
6680_4#22_SMALT
```

All the numbers before `_SMALT` are variable (they are a unique identifier), and the file within the directory will look something like:

```
6680_4#22.bam
```

in this case, again, the numbers before `.bam` are variable (they will match the prefix of the directory, i.e. the i.d. before `_SMALT`). There are similar questions posted, but I'm not that familiar with bash script. Some explanations would be useful, and also, my problem seems complicated by the fact that the file names change in their prefix. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
for dir in `find ./serverfault -maxdepth 1 -type d`
do
  find_output=$( find ${dir} -type f -name "*#*_SMALT" )
  test -z "${find_output}" && echo $dir
done
```

This for loop does the following:

1. Get a list of directories in the specified location.
2. For each directory run a `find` command to look for the desired file name.
3. Check if the output of the `find` command is empty.  If it is print the directory name.

To get the inverse results use `test -n` to check if the output of that `find` command has found something.

**Edit**: I completely misunderstood the question so I rewrote my answer.